# "What lies ahead of our company" or "What lies ahead for our company"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, prepositions

When I checked the [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lie-ahead-of-someone?q=lie%20ahead%20%28of%20someone%29), I found examples of 'of' only. However, when I used it in the following sentence:

> What lies ahead of our company, ...

it didn't make sense to use 'of' for an entity, and I've been advised to use 'for' instead.

Comment: Hello, Ohood. You should check the other dictionary (yes, there are more than two good online dictionaries: I'm making the point that 'the dictionary' is imprecise and unhelpful here) in situations like this. [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lie_ahead) gives a relevant example (further examples, number 5).

Answer (score 1):

"Ahead *of* our company" suggests something that is outside of your company but somehow blocking it's path.

"Ahead *for* our company" implies the discussion of projections for the future of your company.